# AS3 Load external image from url variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to know how to load external image from a URL variable & also how to call the HTML URL variable.

example something: `embed src="http://domain.com/swf/load.swf?imageUrl=http://domain.com/images/image123.jpg" .... />}`

I am trying to make an image player this way. 
Thanks

Comment: Make the code more clear by using four spaces before the line of code

Comment: var imgurl:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_MRKWPTghF8g/TCJiG4-V7kI/AAAAAAAADjE/5CdmrBXZtLU/s1600/exbattery_hen_Beauty.JPG");

Comment: Actually this is a url request
var imgurl:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_MRKWPTghF8g/TCJiG4-V7kI/AAAAAAAADjE/5CdmrBXZtLU/s1600/exbattery_hen_Beauty.JPG");
and I want a variable come from HTML url var something.swf?imageURL=http://domain.com/images/img01.jpq

var imgVar:string = what is in html url variable;
var imgurl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imgVar);

i hope you got it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should as easy as:

1. Making sure the swf is loaded
2. Using [LoaderInfo's parameters object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters) to get to the variables
3. Using the variables as you see fit: job done!

Here's a quick snippet:

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,ready);
function ready(event:Event):void{
   var imageURL:String = this.loaderInfo.parameters.imageURL;
   trace("imageURL",imageURL);
   var loader:Loader = addChild(new Loader()) as Loader;
   loader.load(new URLRequest(imageURL));
}
```

Comment: Thanks George Profenza 
Waooow! it is working 
I am new in AS3 and I will be back if I need any more help.
It was my first time to asking question online 
Thanks Bro

Comment: If it worked, show your appreciation by marking as answered and upvoting the answer ;)